# JavaScript preloaded images are getting reloaded

Tags: javascript

I am preloading images via JS like so:

```
Image1= new Image(234,273)
Image1.src = "001.png"
```

The images successfully get called on page load (confirmed from the Firebug Net panel).

After that, there's a button that triggers a function which replaces an image like so:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = "001.png";
```

The problem is that when that function is called it's reloading the 001.png file, even though it was previously loaded.

Any ideas on why it does that / how to avoid it?

Comment: Have you checked the cache control headers for the images?

Comment: You mean adding something like this to htaccess?

<filesmatch .(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$"="">
Header set Expires "Wed, 21 May 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
</filesmatch>